# Subtitle formatting in tcblisting

Tags: tcolorbox, tcblisting

I tried to use `\tcbsubtitle` in a `tcblisting` environment. It worked such that it produced the subtitle bar; however, the subtitle has a listing format. Demo:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
    \tcbuselibrary{listings}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]

\begin{tcblisting}%
{title=Title,listing only,listing options={escapechar=@,basicstyle=\tiny\ttfamily}}
int main() {
  return 0; 
@\tcbsubtitle{Subtitle}@
  return 1;
}
\end{tcblisting}
    
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

How to have a subtitle in a `tcblisting` with the same format as the title is formatted?

Answer (score 2):

You can change the `subtitle style`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{listings}

\tcbset{
  subtitle style={
    fontupper=\normalfont\large
  }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]

\begin{tcblisting}%
{title=Title,listing only,listing options={escapechar=@,basicstyle=\tiny\ttfamily}}
int main() {
  return 0; 
@\tcbsubtitle{Subtitle}@
  return 1;
}
\end{tcblisting}
    
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it works. Additionally, is it possible to set the subtitle style to match the title style, whatever it is?